# Automatically color balance images

Tags: ruby, image, colors

Is there a way in Ruby to automatically color-balance images that are uploaded to my Ruby on Rails app?

It seems like a lot of the images I'm uploading are too dark and I'd like to normalize all my images to be equally bright if possible, rather than simply making every image brighter. If some image is sufficiently bright, it should not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [rmagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick). Take a look at the [modulate](http://www.simplesystems.org/RMagick/doc/image2.html#modulate) method, perhaps that would help.

Comment: Will this automatically balance it to a standard brightness though? It looks like it just lets me adjust the brightness level to a percentage of the current image's level. I'd like to normalize all my images to be equally bright, so that if a sufficiently bright image is uploaded it shouldn't be adjusted (or maybe even adjusted down if it's too bright).

Comment: you would need to devise a formula to determine the current brightness of the image, and adjust it as necessary

Comment: Right. So I guess I'm asking, what is that formula and how to I calculate it. I believe tools like Photoshop can do this.